# How to access the 'node' coordinates of just one 'way' at a time

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, geojson

I am trying to parse a (very) large set of ways into [GeoJson](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#named-crs) LineStrings. A way can contain many many many nodes.

A sample of a two node way is [here](http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=%5Bout%3Ajson%5D%3Bway%28150672234%29%3Bout%20meta%20center%3B%3E%3Bout%20skel%20qt%3B%0A). In trying to loop through the lat/lons of the nodes I keep getting the below error on

```
>>'if element['type'] == "node":'

>> 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

The problem seems to be in how I am accessing my json file.

```
all_data_dict = get_overpass_json_data(line_url)
# all_data_dict has everything the 'node's' that make up the 'ways'


with open(outfile, 'w') as geojson_file:
    for item in all_data_dict['elements']:
    ## item ONLY includes the info for the 'way'
    ## nothing for the 'nodes' that make up the 'way'
```

How is it possible to access the 'node' coordinates of just one 'way' at a time?

Comment: You should improve your question to make clear what you want to know.

Comment: The formatting of the error looks weird, but it looks like it's `element` is an `int`, and so trying to get the attribute 'type' is failing.

Comment: Yeah. It is returning the "changeset": '29434078' (click the link). Hm.